# How do I capture everything after a pattern until I find another instance of the pattern in my text?

Tags: python, regex

More specifically, I'm working with a txt file of a dialogue between a few different speakers. I'm trying to separate out the text according to speaker. The file looks like this:

```
    S1: that's (your schedule.)
    S2: okay
    S1: thanks a lot Sue i think i feel much better now.
    S2: so it's really nice to talk to somebody who's not dropping a class <S1: LAUGH> i have to say. you don't know how many dropped just like_ that's good <WALKS S1 TO THE DOOR>[S1: alright ] okay [S1: thanks a lot Sue ] bye-bye next... you're Marianne?
    S3: yeah. hi
    S2: hi i'm Sue
    S3: hi
    S2: um did she hit you out there?
```

So I've created an empty data frame to store everything that each speakers says. I want everything that S1 says to be stored separately than everything S2 says, and so on.

My problem is I don't know how to capture the text between each speaker ID. So, for example, when it sees 'S1:', it will capture all the text until it sees 'S2:'. Here is what I'm currently working with. The result is 'None'.

```
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Speaker ID', 'Role', 'Genger', 'Utterance', '# of Words', '# of Pronouns', '1st P SG', '1st P PL', '2nd P'])
#print (df)
f=open('Academic_Advising.txt').read()
try:
    pattern=re.search('^S\d+', f).group()
except: AttributeError
pattern=None
print (pattern)
```

Sorry if this is long-winded. I'm just trying to be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imo, use a defaultdict in combination with a simple regular expression:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re

text = """
S1: that's (your schedule.)
S2: okay
S1: thanks a lot Sue i think i feel much better now.
S2: so it's really nice to talk to somebody who's not dropping a class <S1: LAUGH> i have to say. you don't know how many dropped just like_ that's good <WALKS S1 TO THE DOOR>[S1: alright ] okay [S1: thanks a lot Sue ] bye-bye next... you're Marianne?
S3: yeah. hi
S2: hi i'm Sue
S3: hi
S2: um did she hit you out there?
"""

dd = defaultdict(list)
rx = re.compile(r'(S\d+):\s+(.+)', re.MULTILINE)

for match in rx.finditer(text):
    key, value = match.groups()
    dd[key].append(value)

print(dd)
```

Which yields

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, 
    {'S1': ["that's (your schedule.)", 'thanks a lot Sue i think i feel much better now.'], 
     'S2': ['okay', "so it's really nice to talk to somebody who's not dropping a class <S1: LAUGH> i have to say. you don't know how many dropped just like_ that's good <WALKS S1 TO THE DOOR>[S1: alright ] okay [S1: thanks a lot Sue ] bye-bye next... you're Marianne?", "hi i'm Sue", 'um did she hit you out there?'], 
     'S3': ['yeah. hi', 'hi']})
```

You can easily transfer a dict to a dataframe afterwards.

Comment: This is amazing! Thanks for the help! I have one more question. After testing it out, it looks like there are several places in the text where one speaker interrupts another and they don't create a new line for that speakers interruption. They leave in the same body of text as the speaker who was interrupted. This code doesn't seem be able to separate that and append it to the correct speaker. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you on your journey:

```
import re
import pandas as pd 

def main() -> pd.DataFrame: 
    s = """S1: that's (your schedule.)
S2: okay
S1: thanks a lot Sue i think i feel much better now.
S2: so it's really nice to talk to somebody who's not dropping a class <S1: LAUGH> i have to say. you don't know how many dropped just like_ that's good <WALKS S1 TO THE DOOR>[S1: alright ] okay [S1: thanks a lot Sue ] bye-bye next... you're Marianne?
S3: yeah. hi
S2: hi i'm Sue
S3: hi
S2: um did she hit you out there?"""
    messages = {}
    data_rows = []
    splitted = re.split("(S\d+:)", s)
    print(splitted)
    for i, message in enumerate(splitted):
        if (i+1) % 2 == 0:
            print(f"use {message} as key ")
            speaker_id = message
            message = splitted[i+1]
            message_id = messages.get(speaker_id, 0)
            word_count = len(message)
            data_rows.append([speaker_id, message, word_count])
    df = pd.DataFrame(data_rows, columns=["SpeckerId", "Message", "WordCount"])

    print(df.head())
    return df 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```